# Jenkins variable not working with sed command in pipeline

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, sed, pipeline

The Sed command is giving me issues with incorporating the $tag variable witch is equal to "latest${GIT_COMMIT:0:7}". Here is the Sed command:

```
sh "sed -i 's/{BUILD_NUMBER}/$tag/' /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/em-api/dev-nics-emapi-svc-param.json"
```

I obviously want to put into my .json file the commit information but It doesnt pull the actual commit sha. When I take a look at the .json file it inserted the literal definition of the variable which is “latest${GIT_COMMIT:0:4}”. I am trying to do this on a declarative pipeline on my jenkins server running on linux.

I would like it to insert "latestxxxx". Any suggestions on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GIT_COMMIT` is an environment variable available to you; `tag` is a groovy variable, you have set to `'latest${GIT_COMMIT:0:4}'`. So this gets replaced since you are using `"` for your sed command.  But you are using `'` for your sed expression, which then again will not replace environment variables.  So you have basically two options:

- Use `"` to quote the sed command, if you feel safe about the content, that gets replaced (you can use `"""` triple quotes for the whole command to don't have to quote the `"` for groovy)
- Resolve the variable from the environment yourself in groovy (e.g. something like `System.env['GIT_COMMIT].substring(0,4)`)

Comment: Triple quotes is helpful, thanks